# Invalid prop: type check failed for prop "items". Expected Array, got Object

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuetify.js

I got this error on my console

> vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:619 [Vue warn]: Invalid prop: type check failed for prop "items". Expected Array, got Object

[image]

How do I know what line of code caused this ?

Comment: It's pretty opaque in vue, but look at what the component's parent is binding with @items.  I'll bet a dollar that the array you intend to pass is a prop of the object that you've bound, especially if it came from an API

Comment: You probably don't have that much `items` props, so a quick `ctrl + shift + f` should do the trick.

Comment: Can you please share the code in the `fiddle` or `plnkr` so that it will be easy to find out the root cause of the problem.